# How to compile and run C++ with MinGW using Eclipse and CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, configuration, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I would like to do some C++ development on Windows using Eclipse and the [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) plugin. I use Eclipse Helios SR1 and have installed the CDT plugin. I have also installed [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) and now I wrote a simple "Hello World" in Eclipse.

hello.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In Eclipse using the CDT plugin and the MinGW compiler. How can I compile my program? And how can I test run the program from within Eclipse?

Comment: Here is another good resource for installing MinGW on Eclipse: http://chrismwright.wordpress.com/2012/10/13/installing-eclipse-for-cc-and-mingw/ Pretty much a step-by-step installation including Hello World example at the end...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does [Setting up Eclipse CDT on Windows, Linux/Unix, Mac OS X](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/cdt.jsp) work for you?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't set the environment variables for MinGW and MSYS.

Answer (score 6):

After browsing many threads and articles I've found a solution.
Solution tested on Windows 10 x64 on Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) with C/C++ Development Tools 9.2.1.201704050430 and MinGW

**System configuration**

1. Download MinGW. Any distro might work. I used the [distro](http://nuwen.net) recommended on http://isocpp.org/
2. Extract archive into `C:\MinGW` (actually to `C:\`, because archive contains folder `MinGW`)
3. RMB on `This PC` -> `Properties` -> `Additional system settings` -> Tab `Advanced`-> Button `Environment variables`
4. On second table `System variables` click `New`. Name variable `MINGW_HOME` and set path to MinGW install folder `C:\MinGW` and then `OK`
5. Find variable `Path` in table and choose `Edit`
6. In new window click `New` and type `%MINGW_HOME%\bin\`
7. Confirm actions by clickig `OK` in opened windows
8. You can check availability of new tools by typing in command line `g++ --version` You should see something like

`g++ (GCC) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

**Eclipse CDT configuration**

1. Install [Eclipse with CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) or just add [CDT](https://eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) to existing Eclipse installation
2. Go to the folder with installed MinGW (`C:\MinGW\bin\`). Make a copy of file `gcc.exe` (DO NOT RENAME original file!)
3. Rename copied filed to `mingw32-gcc.exe` (You should have both files `gcc.exe` and `mingw32-gcc.exe` in `\MinGW\bin\`)
4. Open Eclipse and select `C\C++` perspective
5. Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `C\C++` -> `Build` -> `Environment`
6. Click `Add` and type `PATH` as name and click on `Variables` and select `Path`. Confirm with `Ok`.
7. Select new variable `PATH` by clicking `Select` and then `Ok`.
8. Restart Eclipse

Now you should be able to compile Hello World program. Just select `New` -> `C++ Project`. Here you should see available MinGW as Toolchain

Answer (score 0):

Just add `MinGW` to System Path(System configuration part in AndriiL's post) is enough. The variable named `PATH` with `${PATH}` as value will be added automatically in `Window -> Preferences -> C\C++ -> Build -> Environment` and you can see `MinGW GCC` as a toolchain option in project wizard. If no PATH variable presented, Eclipse CDT may not load the recent System Path changes in the OS(Click `Select...` and choose `Path variable`, the value may not contain MinGW path), just Exit Eclipse and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

[Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/mingw/8.1.0) is one package manager that allows mingw install with a single command using Windows Powershell.

```
choco install mingw --version=8.1.0
```

After the installation is done, add the below toolchain path to Eclipse->Window->Preferences-> Core Build ToolChains -> User Defined ToolChains.

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
```

Restart eclipse.
The MinGW toolchain should be available for use now in Eclipse.